# Is there a readable pattern for creating nested Protobuf messages in C++?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I'm new to Protobuf and would like to know if there is a good pattern for creating protobuf messages that results in readable code.

You can do it like this:

```
message.mutable_foo()->mutable_bar()->mutable_gazoo->set_gronk(4711);
message.mutable_foo()->mutable_bar()->mutable_gazoo->set_grunk(0xdeadbeef);
message.mutable_foo()->mutable_bar()->mutable_spunk->set_snafu("Boink!");
```

Or like this:

```
auto foo = message.mutable_foo();
auto bar = foo->mutable_bar();
auto gazoo = bar->mutable_gazoo();
gazoo->set_gronk(4711);
gazoo->set_grunk(0xdeadbeef);
auto spunk = bar->mutable_spunk();
spunk->set_snafu("Boink!");
```

But it is not very readable.

I would like to do something along the lines of:

```
message.set_foo(set_bar(set_gazoo(set_gronk(4711),
                                  set_grunk(0xdeadbeef)
                                 ),
                        set_spunk(set_snafu("Boink!"))
                );
```

Perhaps comparable to the Java builder syntax. Is anything like this possible? Is there any more readable code patterns for this?

Comment: nice example of how opinion-based readability is. I would always prefer one of the first two, while the one you would like to write is the least readable imho (though I have to admit that I dislike the builder pattern very much)

Comment: You could use scopes + indentation to get more readability out of the second example (or just skip the `foo` variable). The third one has really bad readability in my eyes (agree with above comment). Ideal formatting depends a lot on the real structure (why exactly are we setting these three values here? What is their relation?) and also on the structure of the surrounding code (you don't want to mix all three of these styles, so you might need to choose slightly suboptimal formattings in some cases to be more coherent overall).

Comment: As it stands, I would say this question is opinion-based (because "readable" is quite subjective, see the comments). If you want to know whether one concrete syntax could be implemented in C++ then focus the question on that. We can tell you whether it (or a similar syntax) is possible, but whether it is more readable will be left for you to judge.

Comment: @MaxLanghof, perhaps I emphasized readability too much in my question. But if I put it like this: Is this the way you use the API or is there another way to use it that is more along the lines of my last example? How is the API used for nested messages in real projects?